# Laravel many to many with column in pivot table

Tags: laravel, pivot, relationship

I have 3 tables:
Worker, payments and private
A private can pay one or more worker and the worker can receive payments from one or more privates.
The payments table contains the 2 foreign key and the amount.
How can I create the relations in the 3 tables with laravel to get all the informations in the db?
For example i want to have for every worker the payments he receives from every private with the amount.

Comment: so worker and private is a `many to many` relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already know laravel relationships.

**Worker.php**

```
public function privates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Private')->withPivot('amount');
}
```

**Private.php**

```
public function workers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker')->withPivot('amount');
}
```

then in your controller

```
$private = Private::create();
$worker = Worker::create();
$amount = 1000;
$private->workers()->attach($worker->id, ['amount' => '$amount']);
                                            ^^^-column in your payment table.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define `many to many` relationship between `Worker` and `Private`

**Worker Model**

```
public function privates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Private::class, 'payments', 'worker_id', 'private_id')
        ->withPivot('amount');
}
```

**Private Model**

```
public function workers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Worker::class, 'payments', 'worker_id', 'private_id')
        ->withPivot('amount');
}
```

this is how you can retrieve all the `privates` of a `worker`

**Controller Function**

```
$privates = $worker->privates;
// this '$privates' contains the 'pivot' table values which contains the 'amount'.
```

this is how you save amount.

**Controller Function**

```
// first $private and $worker need to have saved.
// and then attach particular $worker as below.
$private->attach($worker_id, ['amount' => 1200.00]);
```